# Repeating images followed by another image inside a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just wanted to say thanks in advance. 

First I have a single div that is `Height: 100%` and `Width: 130px` I have a 130x5px image that i want to repeat vertically until i get to 75% of the screen height. Then i want to place another image directly underneath it. I know how to repeat the image vertically. But i am not sure how to attach another image directly below it.

P.S. I want it to all be in the same div so that i can use JQuery to control the div and not just the individual elements inside of it.

Comment: And what is the code that you have attempted to use to replicate this?

Comment: can't you put two divs inside a single div? Have one occupy the top 75% and the second occupy the bottom 25%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
div.snocavotia {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/130/5/) repeat;  
  z-index: 100; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 130px;
  position: relative;
}

div.snocavotia:after {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/130/30/) repeat;
  z-index: 1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 75%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Example: http://cssdesk.com/h2XGc